# Pegar valor input array

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso resgatar o valor array do input que o usuário clicar, esses inputs são de valores dinâmicos.

HTML/PHP

```
<label>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"><input value="<?=$fs_value?>" name="valor" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession"></i>
</label>
```

JS

```
var val = $("input[name=valor]").val();
$.ajax({
    url:'delSession.php',
    type:'GET',
    data:'valor=' + val,
    success:function(data){
        $('.exibeDelSession').html(data);
    }
});
return false;
```

No caso não consigo colocar no value do input name="valor[]" pois não consigo resgatar no script e usando assim ele me traz apenas o primeiro valor independente de qual input clicar.

Serão vários inputs com valores diferentes, queria pegar por name ou input clicado, algo assim.

Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Se tem mais de um button como saber qual é  o correto? Tem mais de um button certo?

Comment: Não está claro onde está o "array". Seriam vários `<input name="valor">`, perfazendo assim um array?

Comment: Já tentou pegar por `id` ?

Comment: sim, serão vários buttons. e o array seria <input name="valor[]"> mas não consigo capturar no js esse array.

Comment: vc vai deletar mais de uma coisa por click?

Comment: por id não Jeferson mas eu não teria de atribuir um valor pra esse id?
id="1" e assim por diante?

Comment: rray, apenas uma exclusão por click

Comment: Summona o ajax no click do button assim você consegue identificar quem foi clicado e pegar o valor correto, já que não está usando `ids`.

Comment: Então rray a delSession.php eu aplico um var_dump($_REQUEST); e nela sempre traz o primeiro valor apenas com o script q passei acima, preciso pegar os outros valores.

Answer (score 5):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var inputs = jQuery('input[name^="valor"]');
  var values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    values.push($(inputs[i]).val());
  }
  
  console.log(values);
  jQuery('#show').html(values.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" name="valor[]" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="2" name="valor[]" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="3" name="valor[]" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="4" name="valor[]" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="5" name="valor[]" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="6" name="valor[]" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="7" name="valor[]" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">

<div id="show">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Defina uma classe no `input`.

`<input value="<?=$fs_value?>" name="valor" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession" class="pegarValor">`

Feito isso, chame a função jQuery pela sua classe.

```
$(".pegarValor").on('click', function(){
    var valor = $(this).val(); // Aqui Pega o Valor do Input
    alert(valor);
    $.ajax({
        url:'delSession.php',
        type:'GET',
        data:{ valor: valor }, // Aqui define a variável que vai para o delSession.pgp
        success:function(data){
            $('.exibeDelSession').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: vou testar zoom, vlw

Comment: Não testa muito que machuca

Comment: Zoom, noo delSession.php eu aplico um var_dump($_REQUEST); para receber o valor, no caso não aparece nada com essa aplicação que você passou, devo ter feito algo errado, vou rever e retorno.

Comment: E se você fizer `var_dump($_GET)` ?

Comment: mesma coisa, não recebe o valor.

Comment: Como está seu código agora, pode postar ?

Answer (score 4):

Bom, Se é que entendi direito sua duvida vc pode passar para uma função colocando o "this" no onclick tipo:

```
<input type="button" value="teste" onclick="minhaFuncao(this)" />

<script>
minhaFuncao(id) {
 //-- codigo, sendo que o id é o elemento input todo
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solução apenas em javascript:

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=valor]');
var tam = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=valor]').length;
for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += input[i].getAttribute('value');
}
```

```html
<input value="1" name="valor" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="2" name="valor" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="3" name="valor" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="4" name="valor" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
<input value="5" name="valor" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession">
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML/PHP

```
<label>
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"><input value="<?=$fs_value?>" name="valor" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSession" class="pegarValor"></i>
</label>
```

JS

```
$("#delSession").focus(function(){
    $(".pegarValor").on('click', function(){
        //var val = $("input[type=button]").val();
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'delSession.php',
            type:'GET',
            data:'valor=' + val,
            success:function(data){
                $('.exibeDelSession').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: segunda aplicação Zoom, só traz um valor como resultado independente de quantos inputs tenha

Comment: Mas é botão, Bruno. Botão só clica em um ao mesmo tempo. Se fosse `checkbox` eu concordaria. Daí você selecionava vários `checkbox` e apertaria um botão para deletar todos os marcados.

Comment: sim, mas imagina q eu tenha 5 inputs, se eu clicar no 3 o resultado sempre será do primeiro nesse script

Comment: Então o problema está na variável do valor, veja o que está trazendo no Inspect Element.

Comment: Note que você tem um erro ` data:'valor=' + val,` deveria ser ` data:'valor=' + valor,`.

Comment: Quanto a pegar o valor so do primeiro, o `this` aponta para o elemento que disparou o evento, entao `valor` via ter o valor do elemento clicado.

Comment: var val = new Array();
                                        $('input[type=button]').each(function(){
                                            val.push($(this).val());
                                        });
consegui trazer os valores separados por ',', mas traz todos agora